# Oracle INSERT statement with selects on different tables

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, relational-database, oracle-xe

I have two tables `table1` and `table2`. Those tables have unique `name` and `id` columns.

I also have a relation / join table, `table1_table2` which has the straight-forward colums `table1_id` and `table2_id`.

What I want to do is to insert a new relation into `table1_table2` knowing the `name`s of the elements in `table1` and `table2` I want to create a relation for. But I need to get their `id`s to insert them into `table_table2`.

What I want is something like that:

```
insert into table1_table2 values ((select id from table1 where name = 'some_name'), (select id from table2 where name = 'another_name'))
```

I also tried using

```
insert into table1_table2 values ((select id from (select id from table1 where name = 'some_name') where rownum=1), (select id from (select id from table2 where name = 'another_name') where rownum=1))
```

which also didn't work.

I understand I can first extract the `id`s if necessary but I'd prefer it to be in one statement.

Edit: I've also tried

```
insert into table1_table2 values (select t1.id, t2.id from table1 t1, table2 t2 where t1.name = 'some_name' and t2.name = 'another_name')
```

which also didn't work

Example data:

```
table1
id name
1  foo
2  bar

table2
id name
1  some
2  data

table1_table2
table1.id table2.id
1         1
```

and now I want to insert

```
table1.id table2.id
2         2
```

into `table1_table2`, but I do only know that the entry in `table1` has the `name` `bar` and the entry in `table2` has the `name` `data`.

Comment: Some sample data and a clearer view of the table structures might help. Do you want the IDs from each table where the names match - for all names, or a specific one, since you've shown `'name'` as fixed? What if a name only appears in one or the other table?

Comment: Please explain what "doesn't work" means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
INSERT INTO table1_table2 (table1_id, table2_id)
    VALUES ( (SELECT id FROM table1 WHERE name = 'some_name'),
             (SELECT id FROM table2 WHERE name = 'another_name')
           );
```

However, I would write it as:

INSERT INTO table1_table2 (table1_id, table2_id)
    SELECT t1.id, t2.id
    FROM table1 t1 JOIN
         table2 t2
         ON t1.name = 'some_name' AND
            t2.name = 'another_name';

Note in this case if there is no match in either table, then no row is inserted at all.  Using `VALUES`, a `NULL` values would be inserted.